Is it possible to do audio metering in expo-av?

import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
const audio = new Audio();

audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true);

audio.onRecordingMetering((metering: any) => {
console.log(`Average power: ${metering.averagePower} dB`);
console.log(`Peak power: ${metering.peakPower} dB`);
});



After console logging an Audio.Recording object from expo-av, I figured that it has a field called isMeteringEnabled, indicating a possibility for audio metering in expo-av. Can someone help me figure out how to do this? Above is the furthest I have gotten with metering. (Of course, you can't construct an Audio object)
